# Is it possible to install old themes and icons in Blender 3.6.4?

Tags: customization, theme

I would like to know if it is possible to install old themes and icons in the current version of Blender. If possible, is it recommended to do so? Can I have problems using an old theme?

This question makes me sound like an old user, but I'm new, I started using Blender this year. The old theme and icons that were the default in previous versions were prettier than the current ones and the icons were easier to identify and differentiate the tools.

[image]

Comment: I doubt you can change to the old icons and the layout will remain the same, but you may find a theme which suits you via the Edit > Preferences > Themes menu and trying the Presets dropdown at the top of that window.

Comment: If you're looking for colored icons, I would recommend trying out [Bforartists](https://www.bforartists.de/download/)

Answer (score 0):

The shown `Blender 2.5` version (2011) was a complete rewrite of the former Blender series, and a lot of internals changed.

The `Blender 2.8` release (2019) was the second complete rewrite. Both times, the whole user interface was completely overhauled.

You may have partial luck with trying to adopt a theme from back to 2.8 with a current releases, although Blender is always under heavy development, and it may need some work to get it working.
But something as old as 2.5 will not work. `Blender 2.5` is a completely different Software than Blender since 2.8.